# How to put remove button beside each word in a dynamic arraylist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I have ArrayList and I read it word by word, how can I create X button beside each word, to remove word. 
As example I have, ArrayList which contain Books, University, Sport, Math and other words. 
I want to add X button beside each word when user click on it, he remove the word from the arraylist.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

U hv tried use gridview with buttons?
after u can get the line and delete the data in ur arraylist.

Aux code:

Solution 1:

```
protected void gv1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    gv1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex); 
}
```

Solution 2: U can get the id after click and delete it in ur arraylist !

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="confirm(are you sure to delete this record" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' runat="server">delete</asp:LinkButton>
```